# Return Search results metadata with model -- rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following search results (json) that I need to tie with a model (I expanded the first one to make it more readable:

```
{"products_matched": 
    { "89": //<-- this is a product ID
        { "lines": {
                "0": {
                    "meta_count": 6, 
                    "metas": {
                        "0": [0, 4], "1": [0, 4], "2": [0, 1], "3": [1, 2], "4": [2, 3], "5": [3, 4] 
                    }
                }, 
                "1": {
                    "meta_count": 5, 
                    "metas": {
                        "0": [0, 4], "1": [0, 4], "2": [0, 1], "3": [1, 2], "4": [2, 3]
                    }
                }
            },
        "product_score": 0.0
        } ,
"82": {"lines": {"0": {"meta_count": 2, "metas": {"0": [0, 4], "1": [0, 4]}}}, "product_score": 0.55},
"60": {"lines": {"0": {"meta_count": 3, "metas": {"0": [0, 4], "1": [0, 4], "2": [3, 4]}}}, "product_score": 0.0},
"10": {"lines": {"0": {"meta_count": 2, "metas": {"0": [0, 4], "1": [0, 4]}}}, "product_score": 0.0}}
}
```

In rails, how can I return both the model object and the associated meta data (lines) attached to id?

What I have so far:

```
product_ids = results["products_matched"].keys   # => ["89", "82", "60", "10"]

products =  Product.where(id: product_ids)     # => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 82, name: ...],[...] ...>
```

I could try to collect / map them together under one instance variable, or I could send them separately, but that leaves the view to marry the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, and I don't know if it is the best, but I just added an `attr_accessor` to the `Product` model.

```
attr_accessor :result
```

Then I loop through the products:

```
product_ids = results["products_matched"].keys   # => ["89", "82", "60", "10"]
@products =  Product.where(id: product_ids)   

@products.each do |p|
    p.result = results["parsers_matched"][p.id.to_s]
end
```